# Checking for enabled/disabled PNP devices in powershell

Tags: powershell

Currently, I am creating a script that will automatically disable one of my Plug-and-Play devices when I open the shortcut. to make it easier I am wanting to put some script that will allow it to automatically check if the device is enabled or disabled.

```
write-host("Disabling Logitech Extreme 3D Pro")
Disable-PnpDevice -InstanceId 'USB\VID_046D&PID_C215\6&fcc8aab&0&3'
exit
```

Currently, it is just disabling the device, and to make it enable it again I will have to make another script or have another user entry. if you need additional information about it, please ask

Comment: What is your *actual* question?

Comment: @DougMaurer I _guess_ what's asked is a solution that toggles the device state instead of blindly enabling or disabling the device.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand the question properly, you would like to first test if the device is enabled or not in order to have it toggle the enabled state.

Something like this should work:

```
$deviceId = 'USB\VID_046D&PID_C215\6&fcc8aab&0&3'
$device   = Get-PnpDevice -InstanceId $deviceId -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue
if ($device) {
    switch ($device.Status) {
        'OK'    { Write-Host "Disabling device"; Disable-PnpDevice -InstanceId $deviceId -Confirm:$false; break }
        default { Write-Host "Enabling device";  Enable-PnpDevice -InstanceId $deviceId -Confirm:$false }
    }
}
else {
    Write-Warning "Device with ID '$deviceId' not found"
}
```